# Destroy datatable tables on modal-close

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal

firstly apologise as this may seen duplicate since I've searched another solutions before proceed this but still can't figure it out. I initialise the Datatables table inside this code:-

```
$('#get_contacts').on('show.bs.modal', function(e)
{
$('#contacts_table').DataTable({
    deferRender: true,
    responsive: true,
    'bPaginate': false,
    'bInfo': false,
    ajax: 'send_sms_lib.php?mode=listContacts',
    columns: [
      {data:'contact_id'},
        {data:'contact_name'},
        {data:'mobile_numb'},
        {data:'contact_id'}
    ],
    'columnDefs': [{
           'targets': 3,
           'searchable': false,
           'orderable': false,
           'render': function (data, type, row){
              return '<input type="checkbox" id="no" name="no" value="'+data+'">';
           }
        }]
  });
/* *comment temporary since I'm doing my own testing*
  $('#group_table').DataTable({
    deferRender: true,
    responsive: true,
    'bPaginate': false,
    'bInfo': false,
    ajax: 'send_sms_lib.php?mode=listGroup',
    columns: [
      {data:'group_id'},
        {data:'group_name'},
        {data:'contact_name'},
        {data:'group_id'}
    ],
    'columnDefs': [{
           'targets': 3,
           'searchable': false,
           'orderable': false,
           'render': function (data, type, row){
              return '<input type="checkbox" id="no" name="no" value="'+data+'">';
           }
        }]
  });

  $('#global_contacts_table').DataTable({
    deferRender: true,
    responsive: true,
    'bPaginate': false,
    'bInfo': false,
    ajax: 'send_sms_lib.php?mode=listGlobalContacts',
    columns: [
      {data:'contact_id'},
        {data:'contact_name'},
      {data:'mobile_numb'},
      {data:'department'},
        {data:'contact_id'}
    ],
    'columnDefs': [{
           'targets': 4,
           'searchable': false,
           'orderable': false,
           'render': function (data, type, row){
              return '<input type="checkbox" id="no" name="no" value="'+data+'">';
           }
        }]
  });

  $('#global_group_table').DataTable({
    deferRender: true,
    responsive: true,
    'bPaginate': false,
    'bInfo': false,
    ajax: 'send_sms_lib.php?mode=listGlobalGroup',
    columns: [
      {data:'group_id'},
        {data:'group_name'},
        {data:'contact_name'},
      {data:'department'},
        {data:'contact_id'}
    ],
    'columnDefs': [{
           'targets': 4,
           'searchable': false,
           'orderable': false,
           'render': function (data, type, row){
              return '<input type="checkbox" id="no" name="no" value="'+data+'">';
           }
        }]
  });*/
});
```

But when I launced the modal, it keeps pop-up the errors as here:-

> DataTables warning: table id=contacts_table - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

I would like to destroy or if possible to say it as de-initialise the table since the modal consist of multiple menu tabs & intend to destroy table of another tabs to re-initialise table from selected. Here's the code where I intend to do the destroy process:-

```
$('#get_contacts').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `.fnDestroy()`:

```
$('#get_contacts').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#contacts_table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
});
```

Comment: it's working! thanks @Nishanth Matha. I've add the rest of datatables code as here:-

`$('#get_contacts').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#contacts_table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
  $('#group_table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
  $('#global_contacts_table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
  $('#global_group_table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
});`

Comment: just try, it's not working as your suggestions. my pleasure to have your check on my answers below to modify it if necessary, so I may test again. thanks! =)

Comment: I try this `$('#get_contacts').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {  $('#contacts_table#group_table#global_contacts_table#glob‌​‌​al_group_table').d‌​a‌​taTable().fnDestr‌​oy(‌​); });` by removing tailing `,` but the table unload, just the header loaded. Is there somewhere I'm still missing?

Comment: still same, cannot work as per your suggestions. but nvm, I'll keep with my first comment & I'm highly appreciate your assistance & supports.

Answer (score 1):

I've try the answers by @Nishanth Matha & add the rest of datatables code as here:-

```
$('#get_contacts').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#contacts_table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
  $('#group_table').dataTable().fnDestroy(); 
  $('#global_contacts_table').dataTable().fnDestroy(); 
  $('#global_group_table').dataTable().fnDestroy(); 
});
```

The result of it is the message as in questions not appears again.